# tmux changes "\" to spacebar when prefix is pressed

Tags: configuration, tmux, remap

In `tmux.conf` I have mapped `\` (alt gr + q) to rename session and it worked fine up until few months ago, then stopped responding to `\` when prefix is activated.

By chance I've figured out that tmux somehow started responding to spacebar for session rename when prefix is pressed.
I have remapped it to other characters for testing purposes and only `\` is not responding and is changed to spacebar, this is happening even after fresh Linux installation.

Intrestingly, it does recognize `\` when it's written out in terminal or any CLI editor and it's not problem with UTF8 because I've played with different option:

- start tmux with tmux -u
- UTF8 option enabled in .tmux.conf although it enabled by default
- third solution had something to do with changing two language options from terminal to UTF8

Configuration for session and window rename

```
# Rename session and window
bind \  command-prompt -I "#S" "rename-session -- '%%'"
bind |  command-prompt -I "#W" "rename-window -- '%%'"
```

Tmux version is 3.2, I couldn't find anything regarding this problem in `man` or in tmux issues on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tmux 3.0 made two incompatible changes in config file parsing. One is

> a `\` on its own must be escaped or quoted as
> either `\\` or `'\'` (the latter works on older tmux versions).

See [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES#L636). So you should try `bind \\ ...` or `bind '\' ...` instead.